# SQL help to run Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I'm trying to add three new fields from RT_Salesforce DE to the existing data extension (CustomerRet) that I have running SQL through automation studio so that it runs every hour. The following code

> ```
> SELECT
> L.subscriberkey,
> RT.ID AS recordtypeid,
> RT.Name AS casename,
> RT.Subject AS objecttype
>
>
> FROM RT_Salesforce RT
>   LEFT JOIN Opp_Salesforce OS
>   ON RT.ID = OS.RecordTypeID 
> LEFT JOIN CustomerRet L
> ON OS.contactkey = L.subscriberkey
> ```

CustomerRet is my targeted DE, RT_Salesforce is DE which has three fields that I want to add into CustomerRet (recordtypeid, casename, objecttype) however, it does not contain subscriberkey. So what I did was to left join to Opp_Salesforce based on RecordTypeID and then left join again based on matching contactkey matching subscriberkey.

I want the the 3 fields data to sync into matching subscriberkey whilst those that do not match can be left as null.

I've already created the three fields in the targeted DE but was concerned if this is the right approach and if I had missed anything in the code or steps?

I can clarify more so please let me know if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: The only potential issue is that if a record in Opp_Salesforce does not have RecordTypeID, it will not be passed along in this query. I only mention this because you say you want the 3 fields to be null if there is no match. When using the condition on matching RecordTypeID, you will not get any null values from there. You might want to switch the FROM/LEFT JOIN so that it instead pulls all from OS instead